# Occurred error : CvCapture_MSMF::grabFrame videoio(MSMF): can't grab frame. Error: -2147483638

Tags: python, windows, opencv, webcam, ms-media-foundation

I'm a beginner for python.
as below code. I need to record vedio,but after run code. it not show the image.

please help me

python 3.9
opencv 4.6

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
result = cv2.VideoWriter('Output.avi', fourcc, 60.0,(640,480))

while (cap.isOpened()): # check Video 
    check , frame = cap.read() 
    if check == True : 
        cv2.imshow("Output", frame)
        result.write(frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("e"):
            break

result.release()
cap.release() 
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I try to check camera device. so i open them by application. it can work normally

Comment: try `CAP_MSMF` and `CAP_DSHOW` for `apiPreference` argument. the DSHOW backend usually works because it is more mature. the MSMF backend of OpenCV is less well developed.